# PHPUnit via WP-CLI: Warning: Cannot modify header information ... bootstrap.php:68

Tags: wp-cli, unit-tests

I'm trying to setup unit tests for a plugin I am developing.  I just followed the steps at... https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/plugin-unit-tests/

However, when I run `phpunit` I get the following...

```
$ phpunit
Installing...
Running as single site... To run multisite, use -c tests/phpunit/multisite.xml

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/bootstrap.php:68) in /Users/<USERNAME>/Sites/<MYSITE.COM>/wp-load.php on line 64
```

I am running...

- Mac OS 10.12.6
- PHP v5.6.30
- PHPUnit 4.8.36
- MAMP Pro 4.2

The error noted, `bootstrap.php:68` which is the start of the program outputting the "Installing..." text from the output noted above.  Line 68 reads...

```
system( WP_PHP_BINARY . ' ' . escapeshellarg( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/install.php' ) . ' ' . escapeshellarg( $config_file_path ) . ' ' . $multisite );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the code tried to output a HTTP response header with the `header()` function after the response body has already begun to be sent. As you noted, line 68 of `bootstrap.php` is calling that script that outputs `Installing...`. So after that output has already been sent, you can't send a response header.

The next step to debug this is to find out why a response header is being sent. That isn't supposed to be happening, because here we are running the tests from the command line, we're not actually sending a page to the browser.

So, we need to see where `header()` is being called. The error tells you that it is in `wp-load.php` on line 64:

```
    header( 'Location: ' . $path );
```

This line itself doesn't tell us much, but we find that it is within a big `if ... else` statement:

```
/*
 * If wp-config.php exists in the WordPress root, or if it exists in the root and wp-settings.php
 * doesn't, load wp-config.php. The secondary check for wp-settings.php has the added benefit
 * of avoiding cases where the current directory is a nested installation, e.g. / is WordPress(a)
 * and /blog/ is WordPress(b).
 *
 * If neither set of conditions is true, initiate loading the setup process.
 */
if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php') ) {

    /** The config file resides in ABSPATH */
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );

} elseif ( @file_exists( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php' ) && ! @file_exists( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-settings.php' ) ) {

    /** The config file resides one level above ABSPATH but is not part of another install */
    require_once( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php' );

} else {

    // snip

    header( 'Location: ' . $path );

    // snip

}
```

Essentially what this tells us is that `wp-load.php` is looking for the `wp-config.php` file, and isn't finding it. So it is initiating the set-up process, and as part of that it is trying to redirect to the installation page by sending the `Location` header.

So you apparently have not set up your `wp-config.php` file correctly.

The `wp-config.php` file was supposed to be set up by the script you ran though, so this is likely an indicator that something failed. In fact, since we are running the tests here, the `wp-tests-config.php` file is expected to be used instead. So the next step is figuring out why `wp-tests-config.php` isn't being loaded. You should be able to find that file in the `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/` directory.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!  I tried fully reinstalling the test WordPress install (with `bash bin/install-w-tests.sh...`) but still had the same issue with no errors that I saw in the output.  After checking to see where it was looking for the wp-config.php file I noticed it was looking for it in /tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php so I just created a symlink to the one in wordpress-tests-lib using `ln -s /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php /tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php`   It is now working although I'm not sure why I needed to manually create the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

That problem sounds like your code is sending text/characters to the screen, then it sends out a page 'header' (the `<head>` part of an HTML page). PHP doesn't like that; once you put any characters on the screen, you can't send out page headers (the `<head>` part).

Sometimes it is as simple as a space character in front of the `<?php` code. Check for that, or any other text sent out before the page header.

Comment: Actually, this isn't referring to the `<head>` of an HTML document but to an HTTP response header. But it's true that space in front of an opening PHP tag (or after a closing one) can cause this. That isn't the case this time, however.

Comment: @J.D.  You are correct, of course. Wrote a quick response, and my old brain couldn't come up with HTTP Response Header. Thanks.